# Espaço entre as linhas do Paragraph iTextPdf

Tags: java, android, itext

Estou usando um texto muito grande e adicionando direto no Paragraph do iTextPDF, porém o espaço entre as linhas é muito grande, queria controlar o espaçamento entre as linhas, porém não consigo fazer nenhuma alteração, tentei em Font, Chuck e Paragraph, mas sem sucesso...

Segue o Exemplo do que acontece e do que quero...

Acontece:

```
  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto 



  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto



  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto 



  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
```

O que eu quero:

```
  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto 
  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto 
  Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
```

Segue meu pequeno código (Os dados já são adicionados)...

```
            //Código...

            Font f3 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8f, Font.NORMAL);
            f3.getCalculatedLeading(1f);
            f3.setSize(5f);
            paragraph.setFont(f3);
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(9.5f);//Movimenta horizontal
            paragraph.setLeading(40f);//Movimenta vertical
            paragraph.setFirstLineIndent(20f);

            //Código...
```

Comment: `setLeading()` determina o espaçamento entre linhas. Tipograficamente 1.25 o tamanho da font dá um resultado agradável.

Comment: Estou usando o "setLeading" para movimentar na vertical, agora que percebi que este método é para controlar o espaçamento das linhas, como faço para movimentar livremente um Paragraph na vertical???

Comment: Nesse caso é necessário meter o `Paragraph` dentro de uma tabela.